# jQuery fallback function for CSS calc

Tags: jquery, css, function

I am trying to write a function in jQuery, which is designed to support browsers that do not support the CSS calc attribute.

I have the following so far:

```
function calc($element, $xy, $logic, $difference) {
    var calc = $($object).$xy() $logic $difference;
    return calc;
}

if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 8) {
    var height = calc("body", "height", "-", "80");
    $("div#page").css("height", height);
}
```

I can get away without having a function this one time, but for future reference, I think having this function would be really useful.

Obviously this line:

```
var calc = $($object).$xy() $logic $difference;
```

...is going to fail, but I don't know how to pass the variables into it properly.

If anybody has any advice on the syntax, or how I should be writing this line, that would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function calc( selector, method, adjust ) {
    return $(selector)[method]() + adjust;
}

if( $.browser.msie  &&  $.browser.version <= 8 ) {
    var height = calc( 'body', 'height', -80 );
    $('div#page').css( 'height', height );
}
```

A few notes on that code:

- You don't need the `$` prefix on your function parameters. If you're writing jQuery code, I recomment using a `$` prefix only on variables that are references to jQuery objects, e.g.

  ```
  var $foo = $('#foo');  // cache jQuery object for later use
  ```
- Note the square brackets used with `[method]` - that's how you can call a method whose name is stored in a variable.
- I combined the math operation and value into a single `adjust` parameter. You could do something fancier, but it would be good to see more examples of how this code would be used first.

And a suggestion: if you are having to write JavaScript to do the sizing on browsers that don't support CSS calc, why not just use the JavaScript code in *all* browsers? Then you have only one code/style setup to debug instead of two.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much, again for the syntax advice this is really useful. Regarding your suggestion, yes this would seem a logical approach.